# Didn't hear back from the company after confirming Skype Interview. Good Sign or Bad Sign?

Tags: interviewing

So I receive an email from a company asking me for a Skype interview, I confirm it but I never hear back from them regarding any confirmation from their side. That's almost a week ago.

Moreover, I have one other interview for which I would have to travel one day in advance and the times are clashing with my travel. So I send them an email asking them for a possible reschedule but I haven't heard back from them still.

Is it a good sign or bad sign? Or Am I being rude here?

Answer (score 3):

> So I send them an email asking them for a possible reschedule but I
>   haven't heard back from them still.
>
> Is it a good sign or bad sign? Or Am I being rude here?

It's a bad sign.

You may have the wrong email address, or the addressee may be on vacation.

Call. Speak to someone. Confirm the schedule by voice, or confirm that they are no longer interested. Stop trying to do everything by email - it's clearly not working out here.

Comment: The thing is they don't have any phone numbers listed on their site but fortunately I got back from them & they rescheduled my interview :)